# Why does particle measurement cause quantum wavefunctions to collapse

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, measurements, measurement-problem, wavefunction-collapse

When we attempt to measure a certain property of a particle, how and why does its wave function collapse? I've tried to find answers on my own, but they've been far too complicated for me to comprehend. Would appreciate any answer with limited complex jargon, and more simplistic explanation, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to look at it is to remember that the wavefunction describing a particle or a system of particles is a mathematical function, a solution of a specific quantum mechanical wave equation, **with specific boundary conditions** . When a measurement is made, an interaction with the system happens that **changes the boundary conditions**. This means that a new mathematical function will describe the particle or the system of particles after the measurement, and this is what is called "collapse", a misleading term. A wavefunction is not a balloon.

Answer (score 2):

It postulates III that says,

> If the particle is in a state $|\psi\rangle$, measurement of the variable (corresponding to ) $\Omega$ will yield one of the eigenvalues $\omega$ with probability $P(\omega)\propto |\langle\omega|\psi\rangle|^2$. The state of the system will change from $|\psi\rangle$ to $|\omega\rangle$ as a result of the measurement.

The postulates doesn't have proofs.

---

Another aspect of this postulate says the measurement of the variable $\Omega$ changes the state vector, which is, in general, some superposition of the form
$$|\psi\rangle=\sum_{\omega}|\omega\rangle \langle\omega|\psi\rangle$$
into the eigenstate $|\omega\rangle$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\omega$ obtained in the measurement. Which is called the collapse or reduction of the state vector.

Answer (score 0):

Not only is wave function “collapse” a misleading term, it is also not an intrinsic part of quantum mechanics. There are interpretations of quantum mechanics, such as the [many-worlds interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation), in which a wave function never collapses - it only appears to, due to our limited knowledge. If you loose one sock from a pair you do not describe this as “sock collapse” - the other sock is still out there somewhere, you just don’t know where.